# Doxygen how to show a text as it is?

Tags: c, doxygen

[image]

I have a text like this. And I want to show it in doxygen documentation as it is.
What type of command should I use.

Comment: Please avoid posting code as images. You can [edit] your question and post the code example as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use verbatim, endverbatim.

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbatim

Comment: But it prints '*' as wel. Anyway I solved my problem from this answer

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the box you can use [code{.unparsed}](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcode).

E.g.:

```
/// @code{.unparsed}
/// +---+---+
/// | a | b |
/// +---+---+
/// @endcode
```